# Deserialize named list with jackson to a list

Tags: java, jackson

I want to deserialize json from String.class with this structure:

```
{"listName": [{"prop":"value"},{"prop":"value"}, ... ] }
```

to a `List<PropVo>` , where PropVo contains String prop as a field.

- I don't want to create a wrapper class with `List<PropVo>`
- I don't want to use substring

Is there an option just to deserialize to a list?

Comment: You can deserialize it to `Map<String, List<PropVo>>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a type reference to convert that JSON to a `Map<String, List<PropVo>>`:

```
Map<String, List<PropVo>> m = objectMapper.readValue(string, 
        new TypeReference<Map<String, List<PropVo>>>() {});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use readTree

Example:

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode list = om.readTree(json).path("listName");
List<PropVo> result = Arrays.asList(om.treeToValue(list,PropVo[].class);
```